# ¿Cómo construir un conjunto train and test para una red neuronal de Q & A?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, redes-neuronales

Seguí un [tutorial sobre redes neuronales](https://github.com/andersy005/deep-learning-specialization-coursera/blob/master/01-Neural-Networks-and-Deep-Learning/week4/Programming%20Assignments/Deep%20Neural%20Network%20Application:%20Image%20Classification/Deep%2BNeural%2BNetwork%2B-%2BApplication%2Bv3.ipynb) y después de leer el proyecto [DrQA de Facebook Research Team](https://github.com/facebookresearch/DrQA), quería hacer un proyecto de hasta una semana para adaptar el tutorial a preguntas y respuestas.
Tengo un dataset con preguntas, contextos y respuestas que provienen del contexto y quiero saber si puedo hacer un script de Python `load_data()` que prodría crear los sets: `train_x_orig, train_y, test_x_orig, test_y` para un red neuronal.
El dataset proviene del [dev set de Stanford Question Answering Dataset SQuAD2.0](https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/).

```
{
  "version": "v2.0",
  "data": [
    {
      "title": "Normans",
      "paragraphs": [
        {
          "qas": [
            {
              "question": "In what country is Normandy located?",
              "id": "56ddde6b9a695914005b9628",
              "answers": [
                {
                  "text": "France",
                  "answer_start": 159
                },
                {
                  "text": "France",
                  "answer_start": 159
                },
                {
                  "text": "France",
                  "answer_start": 159
                },
                {
                  "text": "France",
                  "answer_start": 159
                }
              ],
              "is_impossible": false
            },
            ...
            {
              "plausible_answers": [
                {
                  "text": "10th century",
                  "answer_start": 671
                }
              ],
              "question": "When did the Frankish identity emerge?",
              "id": "5ad39d53604f3c001a3fe8d4",
              "answers": [],
              "is_impossible": true
            }
          ],
          "context": "The Normans (Norman: Nourmands; French: Normands; Latin: Normanni) were the people who in the 10th and 11th centuries gave their name to Normandy, a region in France. They were descended from Norse (\"Norman\" comes from \"Norseman\") raiders and pirates from Denmark, Iceland and Norway who, under their leader Rollo, agreed to swear fealty to King Charles III of West Francia. Through generations of assimilation and mixing with the native Frankish and Roman-Gaulish populations, their descendants would gradually merge with the Carolingian-based cultures of West Francia. The distinct cultural and ethnic identity of the Normans emerged initially in the first half of the 10th century, and it continued to evolve over the succeeding centuries."
        },
...
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Para resumir con una representación gráfica, aquí es cómo se ve el archivo json.

[image: ![json file description]

El archivo tiene una raiz llamada `data`. `data` contiene el título de un articulo de Wikipedia, `title`, and `paragraphs`. En `paragraphs` tenemos `qas`, para "question and answers", . contexto en `qas`...

Y quiero obtenerlo de esta manera:

```
train_x_orig, train_y, test_x_orig, test_y, classes = load_data()
```

Con `train_x_orig`, `test_x_orig` la pregunta y el párrafo y `train_y` y `test_y` las repuestas.

#### Tentativo

Por el momento hice :

```
# for train and test
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# for the file
import json

def load_data():
    
    with open('dev-v2.0.json') as f:
        source = json.load(f)

    contexts_questions = []
    answers = []

    # We extract and create a line of context question and answer
    for data in source['data']:
        for paragraphs in data['paragraphs']:
            context = paragraphs['context']
            for qas in paragraphs['qas']:
                question = qas['question']
                if qas['answers']:
                    answer = qas['answers']
                elif qas['plausible_answers']:
                    answer = qas['plausible_answers']
                contexts_questions.append([context, question])
                answers.append([answer])
    
    # split in train and test sets
    train_x_orig, test_x_orig, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(contexts_questions,answers)
    return train_x_orig, train_y, test_x_orig, test_y
```

Parece que funciona bien, pero todavía no he logrado encontrar una arquitectura para las preguntas sin respuesta en el texto.

```
index = 10
print("Context:")
print (train_x_orig[index][0])
print("Question:")
print (train_x_orig[index][1])
print("Answer:")
print (train_y[index])
```

En efecto como puede verse aquí:

```
Context:
Gasquet (1908) claimed that the Latin name atra mors (Black Death) for the 14th-century epidemic first appeared in modern times in 1631 in a book on Danish history by J.I. Pontanus...
Question:
In what year was J.I. Pontanus born?
Answer:
[[{'answer_start': 9, 'text': '1908'}]]
```

La respuesta no es buena. La pregunta era `"is_impossible": "true"`

Comment: Marine no debería ser `context_question_answer.append([context, question, answers])` en vez de `context_question_answer = [context, question, answers]` en todo caso...

Comment: @FJSevilla Gracias, modifiqué

Comment: @Marine1 como puedo ponerme en contacto contigo, me interesa mucho sobre ia

Comment: @x-rw chat ? O agregué mi contacto a mi perfil ;)

Answer (score 2):

## 1. Extracción de los datos

Primero de todo, te recomiendo convertir los datos en una tabla (`DataFrame`) de [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/); te permitirá manejar los datos para usarlos con `sklearn` más fácilmente y de manera más eficiente:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

DATA_PATH = "dev-v2.0.json"

CONTEXT_PRIMARY_KEY = ["article", "paragraph_no"]
QUESTION_PRIMARY_KEY = CONTEXT_PRIMARY_KEY + ["question_no"]
ANSWER_PRIMARY_KEY = QUESTION_PRIMARY_KEY + ["answer_no"]


def load_data():
    with open(DATA_PATH) as f:
        source = json.load(f)

    contexts = []
    questions = []
    answers = []
    plausible_answers = []

    # We extract and create a line of context question and answer
    for article in source["data"]:
        for paragraph_no, paragraph in enumerate(article["paragraphs"]):
            context = {
                "article":      article["title"],
                "paragraph_no": paragraph_no,
                "text":      paragraph["context"],
            }
            contexts.append(context)

            context_fk = {k: context[k] for k in CONTEXT_PRIMARY_KEY}
            for question_no, qas in enumerate(paragraph["qas"]):
                question = {
                    **context_fk,
                    "question_no":       question_no,
                    "text":     qas["question"],
                    "is_possible":       not qas["is_impossible"],
                }
                questions.append(question)

                question_fk = {k: question[k] for k in QUESTION_PRIMARY_KEY}
                for answer_type in ("answers", "plausible_answers"):
                    dest = locals()[answer_type]
                    for answer_no, answer in enumerate(qas.get(answer_type, [])):
                        dest.append({
                            **question_fk,
                            "answer_no": answer_no,
                            "text":  answer["text"],
                            "start": answer["answer_start"]
                        })

    contexts_df = pd.DataFrame(contexts).set_index(CONTEXT_PRIMARY_KEY)
    questions_df = pd.DataFrame(questions).set_index(QUESTION_PRIMARY_KEY)
    answers_df = pd.DataFrame(answers).set_index(ANSWER_PRIMARY_KEY)
    plausible_answers_df = pd.DataFrame(plausible_answers).set_index(ANSWER_PRIMARY_KEY)

    return contexts_df, questions_df, answers_df, plausible_answers_df
```

Nótese que aquí aún no he aplicado ningún `train_test_split`, esto lo haré en un paso posterior; este `load_data` simplemente carga y interpreta los datos del archivo JSON y los guarda en varias `DataFrame`s. En particular, crea cuatro `DataFrame`s: los contextos, las preguntas, las respuestas correctas (`answers`), y las respuestas plausibles (`plausible_answers`). Esta separación evita duplicar los datos del contexto en cada pregunta y los datos de cada pregunta en cada respuesta, permitiendo así una manipulación más precisa y individualizada de los datos.

Cada contexto está indexado (únicamente identificado) por el **título del artículo** y el **número de párrafo** (según el orden en que aparecen en el archivo); cada pregunta está indexada por el identificador de contexto (compuesto de lo antedicho) más el **número de pregunta** relativo al contexto (de nuevo, según el orden en que aparecen en el archivo); y cada respuesta está indexada por el identificador de pregunta más el **número de respuesta** (la numeración de `answers` y `plausible_answers` es distinta, con lo cual no se puede mezclar la una con la otra). (Esto es lo que representan las constantes `CONTEXT_PRIMARY_KEY`, `QUESTION_PRIMARY_KEY` y `ANSWER_PRIMARY_KEY`; el término [*primary key*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key) proviene del mundo de bases de datos relacionales.)

Estas `DataFrame`s tienen este aspecto:

```
>>> cdf, qdf, adf, padf = load_data()
>>> cdf
                                            context
article paragraph_no                               
Normans 0             The Normans (Norman: Nourm...
        1             The Norman dynasty had a m...
        2             The English name "Normans"...
                                             ...
Force   41            For certain physical scena...
        42            The connection between mac...
        43            The pound-force has a metr...

>>> qdf
                                                           text  is_possible
article paragraph_no question_no                                            
Normans 0            0            In what country is Normand...         True
                     1            When were the Normans in N...         True
                     2            From which countries did t...         True
                                                         ...          ...
Force   43           6            What is the force exerted ...        False
                     7            What force leads to a comm...        False
                     8            What force is part of the ...        False
[11873 rows x 2 columns]

>>> adf
                                              text  start
article paragraph_no question_no answer_no               
Normans 0            0           0          France    159
                                 1          France    159
                                 2          France    159
                                            ...    ...
Force   43           4           2          sthène    665
                                 3          sthène    665
                                 4          sthène    665
[20302 rows x 2 columns]

>>> padf
                                                      text  start
article paragraph_no question_no answer_no                       
Normans 0            5           0                 Normans      4
                     6           0                Normandy    137
                     7           0                   Rollo    308
                                                    ...    ...
Force   43           6           0          kilogram-force     82
                     7           0          kilogram-force    195
                     8           0          kilogram-force    383
[5930 rows x 2 columns]
```

Si es necesario, podemos obtener una tabla con todos los datos uniendo las subtablas mediante [`DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```py
from functools import reduce

def join(prefixes, how='inner'):
    prefixed = (df.add_prefix(p) for p, df in prefixes.items())
    return reduce(lambda l, r: l.join(r, how=how), prefixed)
```

```
>>> join(dict(context_=cdf, question_=qdf, answer_=adf))
                                                                     context_text                  question_text  question_is_possible     answer_text  answer_start
article         paragraph_no question_no answer_no                                                                                                                  
1973_oil_crisis 0            0           0          The 1973 oil crisis began ...  When did the 1973 oil cris...                  True    October 1973            29
                                         1          The 1973 oil crisis began ...  When did the 1973 oil cris...                  True    October 1973            29
                                         2          The 1973 oil crisis began ...  When did the 1973 oil cris...                  True    October 1973            29
                                                                           ...                            ...                   ...             ...           ...
Yuan_dynasty    46           4           0          The Central Region, consis...  What was the Chinese name ...                  True  Zhongshu Sheng           287
                                         1          The Central Region, consis...  What was the Chinese name ...                  True  Zhongshu Sheng           287
                                         2          The Central Region, consis...  What was the Chinese name ...                  True  Zhongshu Sheng           287
[20302 rows x 5 columns]
```

Obsérvese que he modificado ligeramente la arquitectura de los datos originales:

- En vez de usar `is_impossible`, he negado el predicado para obtener `is_possible`. (Opino que es mejor costumbre usar variables que indiquen el predicado en positivo y no en negativo, ya que es más legible `is_spam` y `not is_spam` que `not is_not_spam` y `is_not_spam`—nótese la doble negación implícita.)

## 2. Cuestiones de diseño

### 2.1. Tratamiento de preguntas sin respuesta correcta

Antes de proceder a hacer nada con los datos, es menester plantearse ciertas cuestiones de diseño. En particular:

- ¿Precisamente, cuál queremos que sea el input/output de la red neuronal?
- ¿Cuando entrenemos la red neuronal, como tratamos la distinción entre respuestas válidas y respuestas plausibles (en el caso que la pregunta no tenga una respuesta correcta)?

Primero es importante hacer una observación: este conjunto de datos en realidad está compuesto de dos conjuntos de datos fundamentalmente distintos: el que corresponde a las preguntas que tienen respuesta correcta y el que corresponde a las que no. No podemos mezclar los dos sin distinción alguna: por ejemplo, no podemos forzar la red neuronal a producir una respuesta y comparar ésta con la respuesta correcta si la hay o la respuesta plausible si no, porque son casos distintos—sería como entrenar un modelo para reconocer dígitos escritos a mano dándole datos compuestos tanto de dígitos como de imágenes de gatos.

Dicho esto, se me ocurren dos opciones principales para responder a las preguntas anteriores:

- Una opción es simplemente extraer cada uno de los dos subconjuntos susodichos y entrenar dos modelos distintos: uno que predice la respuesta correcta dada una pregunta que *sí* tiene respuesta correcta, y otro que predice una respuesta plausible dada una pregunta que *no* tiene respuesta correcta.
- Otra opción, que parece ser que es la que quieres y la que se espera en el SQuAD, es que el output del modelo pueda incluir un valor especial (por ejemplo `"<No Answer>"`) que indique que la predicción es que *no existe una respuesta correcta*. En este caso los datos de `plausible_answer` no se usarían (simplemente se usarían las columnas `answer_text` y `question_is_possible`), a menos que se quieran usar para la métrica de evaluación del modelo (por ejemplo, si el modelo da una respuesta cuando no existe una respuesta correcta, en vez de asignarle una "puntuación" de 0 directamente, se puede comparar la respuesta dada con la lista de respuestas plausibles, y si es una de ellas, asignar una puntuación de 0,5).

De aquí en adelante asumiré que se ha escogido la segunda opción.

### 2.2. Métrica de entrenamiento de la red neuronal

Otra decisión que se debe tomar es qué métrica de entrenamiento (*loss function*) usaremos para la red neuronal, que es menos fácil de lo que parece.

Para empezar, en los datos que tenemos, cuando existe, no hay una única respuesta correcta, sino que hay una lista de longitud variable. Cuando nuestro modelo esté entrenado, podemos definir una métrica de evaluación sencilla que asigne un valor de 1 a una predicción que corresponda exactamente a una de las respuestas de la lista, y 0 en cualquier otro caso. Pero el problema es que las redes neuronales requieren que la métrica de entrenamiento (la que se usa a cada iteración del algoritmo calculando el [gradiente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradiente) de la misma para actualizar los parámetros de la red mediante [*backpropagation*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagaci%C3%B3n_hacia_atr%C3%A1s)) requieren que sea una función **contínua y diferenciable**, lo que la antedicha métrica no es, por ser discreta.

Una opción de métrica diferenciable que se me ocurre es la siguiente, que es simple pero probablemente insuficiente para obtener buenos resultados, y necesita que se seleccione una única respuesta como correcta. Si hacemos que la red neuronal produzca dos números como output, indicando los índices de inicio y fin del subtexto que corresponde a la respuesta, podemos definir la pérdida (*loss*) como la longitud de la intersección de la subsecuenia predecida con la subsecuencia correcta, normalizada por la longitud de la subsecuencia correcta, pero con el signo negado. Es decir, si `(a, b)` representa la respuesta correcta y `(x, y)` es la predicción, esta métrica tendría la siguiente fórmula:

```
f((x, y), (a, b)) := -max(0, min(y, b) - max(x, a))/(b - a)
```

Esta función tiene un valor de 0 si la predicción no intersecciona con la verdad y un valor de 1 si es idéntica. Es diferenciable en todo su dominio salvo cuando `min(y, b) == max(x, a)` , `x == a` o `y == b`.

## 3. Extracción de los datos para el entrenamiento

Para saber exactamente cómo extraer las matrices `X_train`, `X_test` y los vectores `y_train` , `y_test`, tenemos que saber cuál es la métrica de entrenamiento que se va a usar, cosa que no dices en tu pregunta.

Pero ya que dices

> Y quiero obtenerlo de esta manera:
>
> ```py
> train_x_orig, train_y, test_x_orig, test_y, classes = load_data()
> ```
>
> Con `train_x_orig`, `test_x_orig` la pregunta y el párrafo y `train_y` y `test_y` las repuestas.

voy a mostrar cómo se hace eso. He interpretado que `train_y` y `test_y` son vectores cada elemento de los cuales es una lista de respuestas *correctas*, si las hay, (con únicamente el texto de cada respuesta), o un valor especial tipo `NaN`/`None` si no.

```py
adf_squashed = adf.groupby(adf.index.names[:-1]).aggregate(list)
df = join(dict(context_=cdf, question_=qdf, answers_=adf_squashed), how='left')
X, y = df[["context_text", "question_text"]], df["answers_text"]
```

Hasta ahora solo hemos extraído la matriz de atributos (`X`) y el vector de respuestas (`y`):

```
>>> X
                                                           context_text                  question_text
article         paragraph_no question_no                                                              
1973_oil_crisis 0            0            The 1973 oil crisis began ...  When did the 1973 oil cris...
                             1            The 1973 oil crisis began ...  What was the price of oil ...
                             2            The 1973 oil crisis began ...  When was the second oil cr...
                                                                 ...                            ...
Yuan_dynasty    46           7            The Central Region, consis...  Where was the Central non-...
                             8            The Central Region, consis...   What modern city did Khan...
                             9            The Central Region, consis...   What was the Japanese nam...

>>> y
article          paragraph_no  question_no
1973_oil_crisis  0             0              [October 1973, October 197...
                               1              [nearly $12, $12, $12, $12...
                               2              [1979, 1979, 1979, 1979, 1...
                                                          ...              
Yuan_dynasty     46            7                                        NaN
                               8                                        NaN
                               9                                        NaN
Name: answers_text, Length: 11873, dtype: object
```

Nótese que para las preguntas que no tienen respuesta exacta, el valor de `answers_text` es `NaN`. Si quisiérase usar listas vacías en vez de `NaN`, se puede hacer:

```
>>> y.apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, list) else [])
article          paragraph_no  question_no
1973_oil_crisis  0             0              [October 1973, October 197...
                               1              [nearly $12, $12, $12, $12...
                               2              [1979, 1979, 1979, 1979, 1...
                                                          ...              
Yuan_dynasty     46            7                                         []
                               8                                         []
                               9                                         []
Name: answers_text, Length: 11873, dtype: object
```

Finalmente podemos usar `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` para dividir entre train y test:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split
```