# ¿Cómo tokenizar matrices de cadenas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, tokens, nltk

Tengo varios arreglos de diferentes cadenas y quiero convertir las cadenas en tokens. Intenté dos aproximaciones:

1. Aplicar la `word_tokenize` de `nltk.tokenize`

   ```
   word_tokenize(train_x_orig)
   ```

   Pero no puedes aplicar `word_tokenize` a matrices directamente.
2. El método `str.split()`.
3. `RegexTokenize` de `nltk.tokenize`:

   ```
   # tokenize
   tknzr = RegexTokenizer('\w+')
   train_x_orig = [[tknzr.tokenize(train_x_orig) for word in str] for str in train_x_orig]
   ```

   Sin éxito porque no podía importar `RegexTokenizer`:

   > ```
   > from nltk.tokenize import RegexTokenizer
   > ImportError: cannot import name 'RegexTokenizer'
   > ```

#### Datos

Todos los datos provienen de aplicar el algoritmo en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/185509/c%C3%B3mo-construir-un-conjunto-train-and-test-para-un-red-neuronal-de-q-a) a este conjunto de datos: Conjunto de Datos de Contestación de Preguntas de Stanford] [2](https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/).

Aquí hay un ejemplo de las diferentes matrices, creo que todavía necesito procesar `train_y`:

```
>>> train_x_orig[0]
['Newborn infants have no prior exposure to microbes and are particularly vulnerable to infection...', 'What antibody is transmitted from the father to the baby?']

>>> train_y[0]
[[{'answer_start': 371, 'text': '0.2 inhabitants per square kilometre'}, {'answer_start': 371, 'text': '0.2 inhabitants'}, {'answer_start': 371, 'text': '0.2 inhabitants per square kilometre'}]]
```

Comment: Typo: el nombre de la clase es incorrecto, es [`from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer`](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#module-nltk.tokenize.regexp), ("Regex**p**Tokenizer" no "RegexTokenizer")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como ya se ha comentado hay un error tipográfico al importar la clase, debiera ser [`nltk.tokenize.regexp.RegexpTokenizer`](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#nltk.tokenize.regexp.RegexpTokenizer).

Aparte de esto, la construcción de la lista por compresión es incorrecta, suponiendo de acuerdo a tu ejemplo que `train_x_origin` es una matriz de la forma:

```
[[frase_1, frase_2, ...],
 [frase_A, frase_B, ...],
  ...
]
```

debes aplicar `tknzr.tokenize()` sobre cada sentencia, no sobre `train_x_orig` que es la matriz completa, debería ser algo como:

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer


train_x_orig = [['Newborn infants have no prior exposure to microbes and are particularly vulnerable to infection...',
                 'What antibody is transmitted from the father to the baby?'
                 ],
               ]

# tokenize
tknzr = RegexpTokenizer('\w+')
train_x_orig = [[tknzr.tokenize(sentence) for sentence in x] for x in train_x_orig]
```

con lo que `for x in train_x_orig` itera sobre cada fila y `for sentence in x` itera sobre cada frase de la fila a tokenizar.

**Salida:**

```
>>> train_x_orig
[
 [
  ['Newborn', 'infants', 'have', 'no', 'prior', 'exposure', 'to', 'microbes', 'and', 'are', 'particularly', 'vulnerable', 'to', 'infection'],
  ['What', 'antibody', 'is', 'transmitted', 'from', 'the', 'father', 'to', 'the', 'baby']
 ]
]
```

Si quieres usar `word_tokenize`:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize


train_x_orig = [['Newborn infants have no prior exposure to microbes and are particularly vulnerable to infection...',
                 'What antibody is transmitted from the father to the baby?'
                 ],
               ]

train_x_orig = [[word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in x] for x in train_x_orig]
```

**Salida:**

```
>>> train_x_orig
[
 [
  ['Newborn', 'infants', 'have', 'no', 'prior', 'exposure', 'to', 'microbes', 'and', 'are', 'particularly', 'vulnerable', 'to', 'infection', '...'],
  ['What', 'antibody', 'is', 'transmitted', 'from', 'the', 'father', 'to', 'the', 'baby', '?']
 ]
]
```

> **Nota:** No uses nunca `str` como nombre de una variable propia, esto enmascara el built-in `str` de Python en ese espacio de nombres, pudiendo provocar resultados inesperados, además de poder confundir a quién lea ese código. Si no tuvieras más remedio usa `str_` en todo caso.

Comment: Gracias FJ ! Sin embargo porque la construcción de la lista por compresión es incorrecta ? Se necesitan los dobles corchetes absolutamente? ¿Cómo transformar los arreglos entonces?

Comment: Debes aplicar `tknzr.tokenize()` sobre cada sentencia, no sobre `train_x_orig` que es la matriz completa, en tu caso debería ser `[tknzr.tokenize(word) for word in str]`, no `[tknzr.tokenize(train_x_orig) for word in str]`. Supongo que `train_x_origin` es una matriz de la forma `[[frase_1, frase_2...], [frase_A, frase_B, ...], ...]`, por lo que `for x in train_x_orig` itera sobre cada fila y `for sentence in x` itera sobre cada frase de la fila a tokenizar.